# status: 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT'

Tags: node.js, google-maps-api-3

Hello I'm a newbie with node.js and javascript. I'm trying to make a request to google maps api and I'm getting status: 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT'. Here is my code:

```
const request = require('request')



request({
    url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1301%20lombardi%20street%20philadephia',
    json: true
}, (error, response, body) => {
    console.log(body)
})
```

here is the error that I have encountered.

> { error_message:    'Keyless access to Google Maps Platform is
>   deprecated. Please use an API key with all your API calls to avoid
>   service interruption. For further details please refer to
>   http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account',   results: [],   status:
>   'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT' }

Answer (score 1):

> As of June 11, 2018, you must enable billing with a credit card and have a valid API key for all of your projects [google maps platform](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform)

You are using geocode api without api key. You should first create an api key and set a credit card for your account to using this api. Base on [this documnet](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/), 40,000 request of this api will be  free monthly